# Multiple Function Parameters?

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters

I have the function:

```
def sendMessage(s, message):
    messageTemp = "PRIVMSG #" + CHANNEL + " :" + message
    s.send((messageTemp + "\r\n").encode())
```

I can output a single message to the chat in a twitch server using this function, but when I want to output a message that has variables in it like so:

```
sendMessage(s, var1, "message1", var2, "message2")
```

I get an error: `TypeError: sendMessage() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given`.

I understand that in the function, it is limited by `(s, message)`, but I was wondering if there was anyway around this? I'll be using this function numerous times throughout my program, each time the amount of variables used will differ so I can't set specific limits for the function.

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate `var1`, `"message1"`, `var2`, and `"message2"` into one string and pass that?

Comment: Could you explain that a bit? I'm new to python/coding in general. If I try to run it like so: sendMessage(s, "var1 message1 var2 message2), it doesn't treat var1 and var2 like variables.

Comment: Briefly: you are sending the wrong number of arguments to the function you defined. Please see a tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either concatenate/interpolate/format your string before passing it into your function:

```
sendMessage(s, var1 + " message1 " + var2 + " message2")
sendMessage(s, "%s message1 %s message2" % (var1, var2))
```

Or you can do like `print()` and accept a variable number of arguments, packing the second through the nth into a tuple, then deal with that however you want in your function. Such as:

```
def sendMessage(s, *message):
    messageTemp = "PRIVMSG #" + CHANNEL + " :" + " ".join(map(str, message))
    s.send((messageTemp + "\r\n").encode())
```

Then the example call you provided will work! As a bonus, the other way still works.

Comment: I did this and it works and I get the correct outcome in the IDE, but it doesn't output it to the twitch chat like my other commands

Comment: After playing around with it I figured it out. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use the `sendMessage()` function in that way, change the definition of the function to allow an unlimited number of parameters. [This part of the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) explains how to do that. If you want to separate the various parts of your message by spaces, you could use

```
def sendMessage(s, *args):
    messageTemp = "PRIVMSG #" + CHANNEL + " :"
    for msg in args:
        messageTemp = messageTemp + " " + str(msg)
    s.send((messageTemp + "\r\n").encode())
```

This combines the string representations of your various parts of your message into one string. This also allows you to use various types for the parts of your message, as long as each type has a suitable string representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "kwargs" as a parameter, which stands for key word arguments. Then the function can accept any number of key value pairs that you want to pass into it. For example:

def sendMessage(s, message, **kwargs)

sendMessage(s, message, var1="message1", var2="message2")